gcc Preprocesor failed on #if
I have strange problem as gcc preprocesor failed on #if directive.
Sample code:
#include "stdio.h"

enum BoardTypes{
    Board_IO_WithAdc,
    Board_IO_WithEnc,
    Board_PakelcIn,
    Board_PakelcOutP,
    Board_PakelcOutV,
};

#define BoardAdr Board_PakelcIn

int main(void){

    #if ((BoardAdr==Board_PakelcOutV) || (BoardAdr==Board_PakelcOutP))
        printf("Board_PakelcOutV or Board_PakelcOutP\n");
    #endif

    #if (BoardAdr==Board_PakelcIn)
        printf("Board_PakelcIn\n");
    #endif
}

the expected result is  Board_PakelcIn but got Board_PakelcOutV or Board_PakelcOutP, Board_PakelcIn.
Clearly something is wrong here.

There's no point in using pre-processor directives. The compiler will optimize a "real if" away.

@ikegami Might warn about the condition being always true/false though.

Actually using real 'if' or preprocesor '#if' makes same code. And in real 'if' the typos are detected. Thanks to point me here.

All your macros expand to something undefined, which is treated as 0.
The preprocessor has no concept of your enum, so your code is essentially just:
#include "stdio.h"

#define BoardAdr Board_PakelcIn

int main(void){

    #if ((BoardAdr==Board_PakelcOutV) || (BoardAdr==Board_PakelcOutP))
        printf("Board_PakelcOutV or Board_PakelcOutP\n");
    #endif

    #if (BoardAdr==Board_PakelcIn)
        printf("Board_PakelcIn\n");
    #endif
}

After replacing BoardAdr with Board_PakelcIn, we get:
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void){

    #if ((Board_PakelcIn==Board_PakelcOutV) || (Board_PakelcIn==Board_PakelcOutP))
        printf("Board_PakelcOutV or Board_PakelcOutP\n");
    #endif

    #if (Board_PakelcIn==Board_PakelcIn)
        printf("Board_PakelcIn\n");
    #endif
}

And now, all of Board_PakelcIn, Board_PakelcOutV and Board_PakelcOutP are undefined and thus 0, so we are left with:
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void){

    #if ((0==0) || (0==0))
        printf("Board_PakelcOutV or Board_PakelcOutP\n");
    #endif

    #if (0==0)
        printf("Board_PakelcIn\n");
    #endif
}


Actually replacing:
enum BoardTypes{
    Board_IO_WithAdc,
    Board_IO_WithEnc,
    Board_PakelcIn,
    Board_PakelcOutP,
    Board_PakelcOutV,
};

with
#define Board_IO_WithAdc    0       
#define Board_IO_WithEnc    1       
#define Board_PakelcIn      2
#define Board_PakelcOutP    3
#define Board_PakelcOutV    4

solve the problem, but need manual enumeration.
